# c++ How can I use a protected assignment operator to do an assignment?

Tags: c++

I am dealing with a class that I cannot tamper with.
This is basically what I have:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        static Base factoryBase()
        {
            return Base();
        }

    protected:
        Base() {};
        Base(Base const & other) {  }
        Base & operator=(Base const & other) { return *this; }
};
```

In essence I have a static factory method, to instantiate the `Base` class.

In my part of the code I want to do this

```
Base b = Base::factoryBase();
```

but this fails because the copy constructor and assignment operator are `protected`. I can only assume that they are so, so that I can use them in a derived class.

How should I go about it though?

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived()
        {
            //Base::factoryBase(); //what do I do here and how do I store the result?
        }
};
```

I am unsure how to assign the result of Base::factoryBase() to the Derived class itself. Is it even possible? How else am I supposed to use the fact that the constructors and assignment operators are `protected` ?

note: compilation is done with earlier that c++11 versions. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: It is strange to me that the copy constructor is even being invoked, that copy should be elided due to [RVO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Comment: Wouldn't `const Base &b = Base::factoryBase();` work? Or does that still check the copy constructor?

Comment: @CoryKramer: Even if copy elision could occurs, copy(/move) constructor should be accessible.

Comment: @melpomene: `const Base &b = Base::factoryBase();` (or `Base&& b = Base::factoryBase();` in c++11) should work.

Comment: @Jarod42 Even if you ignore the copy constructor, don't forget that `operator=` is also protected.  Assigning to any `Base` object, regardless of cv/ref qualifiers, should fail from outside.

Comment: @0x5453: `Base b = Base::factoryBase();` calls copy/move constructor, not assignment.

Comment: @Jarod42 Whoops, you're right.  Forgot about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may still do:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(/*Base::factoryBase()*/) {}

    // Not really useful, but for demonstration
    static Derived factoryDerived() { return Derived(); }
};
```

And then

```
Derived d = Derived::factoryDerived();
```

Comment: Hi there, why do you have `Base(/*Base::factoryBase()*/)`? Is it possible to avoid calling the `Base()` constructor and rely on the static `factoryBase()`?

Comment: @nass: That is the reason of the comment, you might copy construct from the factory if you prefer (by un-commenting that part).

Answer (score 1):

You could call `operator=` directly in the derived class:

```
Derived()
{
    Base::operator=(Base::factoryBase());
}
```